# How does one compute this bayesian probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Assume you have a network as follow (where X->Y implies X is the parent of Y)

> A->D, B->D

How does one compute $P(A,B|D)$?

A and B are independent so my intuition tells me

$P(A,B|D)= P(A|D)\times P(B|D) = [\frac{P(D|A)}{P(A)}]\times[\frac{P(D|B)}{P(B)}]$

but I am not sure.

Comment: No. A and B being independent does not mean that they are conditionally independent given D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.   You cannot infer *conditional independence* from *pairwise independence*.

Applying Bayes' Rule can only obtain:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A, B\mid D) ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(D\mid A, B)~\mathsf P(A,B)}{\mathsf P(D)}
\\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(D\mid A, B)~\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(D)}
\end{align}$$